# Python: How to only pick up the latest message in an email from Outlook

Tags: python, outlook, win32com

I'd like to pick up the latest message only without extract by Re,Fw in an email message from Outlook using Python 3.

```
import win32com.client

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
print(inbox.Items[len(inbox.Items)-1].body)
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, all collections in OOM are 1 based, not 0. Secondly, the Items collection is not sorted in any particular way until you explicitly call `Items.Sort`.

After you call `Items.Sort` specifying "`[ReceivedTime]`" or "`[CreationTime]`" as an argument, you can use `Items.GetFirst` or `Items.GetLast` depending on the direction parameter (second argument to `Items.Sort`).

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.Items.Sort for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Use "Item.GetLast()"

example:

```
import win32com.client

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
folder = outlook.Folders.Item("Your Mailbox")
inbox = folder.Folders.Item("Inbox")
msg = inbox.Items
msgs = msg.GetLast()
print(msgs)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: No, the collection is not sorted in any particular way unless you explicitly call Items.Sort.